# remove overlay from vuetify button

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-btn that I am using inside a component.  The problem is that I need to remove the overlay from the button.  In terms of the API the closest that I can find is the ripple, which is not what I am looking for.  When I view the source I can see that I am getting the overlay from here:

```
.v-btn--plain:not(.v-btn--active):not(.v-btn--loading):not(:focus):not(:hover) .v-btn__content {
  opacity: 0.62;
}
```

I am implementing the view button such as:

```
<v-btn plain class='yellowButton' id='ResourceBtn' @click="SubmitForm()" >Submit</v-btn>
```

I have tried the following CSS, and have had no luck:

```
<style scoped>
.v-btn--plain:not(.v-btn--active):not(.v-btn--loading):not(:focus):not(:hover) .v-btn__content{
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
.yellowButton{
    background-color: #FFD007;
    color: #0033A1 !important;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: -.25px;
    opacity: unset !important;

}
.yellowButton span.v-btn__content{
  opacity:inherit !important;
}
</style>
```

Any suggestions about what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you talking about ripple in v-btn?